How can I calculate the temperature at a distance $r$ from a neutron star?
I am looking for an equation that can take into account the strong magnetic fields of neutron stars and the affect they have on the radiation of heat. So far, I have been unable to find anything more than rough approximations, and even those are for normal stars, not neutron stars. I want to take into account the non-isotropic emission of neutron stars, the gravitational redshift, and the surface anisotropies of neutron stars.

What is the problem with the Black body radiation? Isn't a neutron star a black body?

The reason you have been able to find only approximations is because a neutron star is an enormously complicated system. There will probably be no straight-up equation that tells you exactly how every part of it interacts with every other, at least not one you could easily write out...

@controlgroup Yeah, I understand that but I am just a little lost about which of these approximations is the best.

You might link to which approximations you're considering, and what your application of those approximations is, then - they each might have their own value.

At first, I used =*sqrt(Rs/2r) where Rs is the star's radius, Tb is the body's temperature, and Ts is the surface temperature of a star. I think this is derived from the Stefan-Boltzmann law(I found this in another post but am not sure how to link it). I wasn't sure if I could use black body radiation because of the factors mentioned above affecting the wave lengths.
